# AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'resize' when trying to resize

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I've always struggled with PIL, it is the very bain of my existence. Anyways, I tried resizing an image, and I followed a tutorial word for word, and it still doesn't work for me.

```
# image
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='goldman.png')

# resized image
changer = img.resize((20,20),Image.ANTIALIAS)

goldman_logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(changer)

for x in range(2):
    self.my_label = Label(self.invest_row,image=goldman_logo)
    self.my_label.grid(row=x,column=0)
```

and the error I'm getting is this

```
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'resize'
```

Image is fine, am able to load it if I don't resize.

Comment: A `PhotoImage` has no use other than being displayed in Tkinter.  Any image processing needs to be done on a normal PIL `Image`, before converting it to a `PhotoImage`.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you open and resize PIL images -

```
image = Image.open('goldman.png')
image = image.resize((20,20), Image.ANTIALIAS)
my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
my_img = Label(root,image = my_img)
my_img.pack()
```

Comment: when i try this, the image is not displayed and it is white. However, if i do a normal photoimage, the photo is displayed

Comment: What do you mean be normal photoimage. And also you need to do - `my_img = Label(root,image...)`

Comment: Yep, PIL is difficult to install as well. It does not make a huge difference when you do not use PIL

Comment: @PCM PIL supports a lot more file formats than pure `tkinter`. Also I can't find any way of converting a `numpy` array into a `tkinter` image other than using `PIL`.

Comment: Why are you assigning a `Label` widget to a variable named `my_img`?